# Firestore onSnapshot forEach possible to compare current document's value to "next" document's value?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

When I perform a query in Firestore that returns multiple documents, I use forEach to loop through them in the recommended way, like this:

```
listener=firestoredb.collection('bids').onSnapshot(function(doc){
   doc.forEach(function(doc){
      currentbid=doc.data().bid;
      console.log(currentbid)
   });
});
```

I would like to know if it is possible to compare currentbid to the NEXT document's doc.data().bid value. I thought I would be able to do this by getting the current index, but it does not seem forEach works like iterating through a normal array in this case, I just get "undefined". Can I get an index and ask for (index+1) in some way to compare values?

For example, my code above might return:

```
100
150
300
200
200
100
```

I want to know if currentbid is equal to the NEXT currentbid. So when it gets to the first "200", it would be flagged because the NEXT currentbid would also be "200".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to compare elements in a structure that doesn't allow random access, it so remember the previous item and use that for the comparison.

Something like:

```
listener=firestoredb.collection('bids').onSnapshot(function(doc){
   let latestbid = -1; // or some other value that can't occur
   doc.forEach(function(doc){
      currentbid=doc.data().bid;
      console.log(currentbid)
      if (currentbid === latestbid) {
         console.log(`${currentbid} === ${latestbid}`);
      }
      latestbid = currentbid;
   });
});
```

But you can also just access [`QuerySnapshot.docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs), which **is** a normal array. So:

```
firestoredb.collection('bids').onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot){
   querySnapshot.docs... // is a normal array
```

Comment: Yes, it occurred to me that I could do that, but I want to do the comparison in conjunction with some other logic. Trying to keep my script efficient, rather than having two separate comparisons that do similar things. So this would be my backup if I can't otherwise access the next document. Are you saying in my structure that random access is not possible? I wasn't sure.

Comment: If its not possible to do it the way I described, then this is the best answer. Its definitely a technique that is documented elsewhere, I was wondering if random access was possible within my script using Firestore's data.

Comment: The second snippet I added gives you a regular array that supports random access. If you're having a problem making that work, I'd recommend posting a new question showing what you tried with `querySnapshot.docs`.